# Breaking the line

Tags: reactjs

I use the bubble chart. The problem is that when i write the text in and use \n or for line break it shows me an error.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BubbleChart,key,data } from 'reaviz';
export default function Bubble1() {
  const longData = [
    { key: '48% \n expect 100 bps', data: 800,},
    { key: '14% \n expect 75 bps', data: 250 },
    { key: `${"40%" <br/>"by 100%"}`, data: 400},

  ];
    return (
        <div >
            <BubbleChart data={longData} height={450} width={450} />;
        </div>
    )
}
```

I did every possibility but the result is the same. It shows the text in the same line

Comment: Please show us the `BubbleChart` code that displaying the line break.

Comment: The above code is bubble chart code and the thing is that I want 48% in one line and 100% in the second line.

Answer (score 0):

In normal html tag such as `div`, you can have line break using the `br` tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Or else you should use `\n` in `span` tag.